# IPad: Safari and HTML5. Loading graphic is very slow

Tags: ipad, html, svg

i'm italian, so, excuse me for my bad english. The problem is this....

I'm trying to develop a web-site available for IPad1 by HTML5.
I have to work with a planimetry.
I have taken X and Y coordinates from a Xml file to make this planimetry, and I have drawn it by SVG 'path' tag.
The problem is that, when I interact by fingers, on the IPad, the planimetry image loading is heavy. Every kind of image, like tooltip, which I add on the planimetry and modify it in scale, rotation or traslation by fingers... jumps.
I tried to solve it activating Hardware Acceleration by adding this code in my CSS file

```
#path  { -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); }
```

but nothing!! No change. 
( i have read this solution in forums in which talks about Safari )

Maybe the problem is that i have thousands of path tags (like lines and polylines) to draw.

I hope someone could help me soon

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you simplify the paths?  Are they all shown on the screen at once - you may be able to only load ones that are visible in a given view.  Per @Taze, you might also try fixed image backgrounds - you could achieve different zoom levels by rendering a set of image tiles for each level and swapping them in as in a mapping engine (lots of work!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simply that the processor can't handle drawing that many parts in a short space of time.

Perhaps draw onto the `<canvas>` tag in HTML5, then you could cache the image as a bitmap so it wouldn't need to be redrawn when the page is moved?

Comment: The problem is that planimetry has to be interactive !
I have to capture touch event with one finger. For example, if a user touch a specific room, a tooltip becomes visible and shows information only about that room and so on. Then, with the image of planimetry, i lose quality if a zoom in, right ?

Comment: Accept this response but it's not the solution